# "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I created a simple Django REST framework and I am able to GET. However, when trying to POST I receive the following:

```
"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
```

I have attached my models, urls, views and serializers below.

My Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted([(item, item) for item in get_all_styles()])


class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

serializers.py

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = '__all__'
        #fields = ['id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style']
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('snippets/', views.snippet_list),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/', views.snippet_detail),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view(['GET','POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def snippet_list(request,format=None):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print("the request",request.data)
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

'''this is a pretty simple application of the GET,PUT,DELETE api'''

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def snippet_detail(request, pk,format=None):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
    """
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        snippet.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Why am I able to GET but not POST?

Answer (score 0):

Since your function-based view is using `@api_view` decorator, you don't have to parse the request body as it is already done for you. Just access `request.data`:

```
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
```

It's the same thing as what you currently have for `PUT`.